# Get the value of a computed property in Vue.js and use it in a data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a computed property `countryName` which returns a country name based on a country code and works fine. I need the use the `countryName` value as the value of the `label` of the `country` data property but I get `undefined`.

```
export default {
    props: ['content'],
    data () {
        return {
            countries: require('../../plugins/countries'),
            country: {
                value: this.content.country_code,
                label: this.countryName
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        countryName () {
            return this.countries.find(item => item.value === this.content.country_code).label
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the component is instantiated, the data function is called *before* the computed properties are added to the component. That's why you get `undefined`. Try setting it in `mounted` or `created`.

```
data () {
    return {
        countries: require('../../plugins/countries'),
        country: {
            value: this.content.country_code,
            label: null
        }
    }
},
computed: {
    countryName () {
        return this.countries.find(item => item.value === this.content.country_code).label
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.country.label = this.countryName
}
```

For the curious, this is the `initState` function as of Vue 2.3.3

```
function initState (vm) {
  vm._watchers = [];
  var opts = vm.$options;
  if (opts.props) { initProps(vm, opts.props); }
  if (opts.methods) { initMethods(vm, opts.methods); }
  if (opts.data) {
    initData(vm);
  } else {
    observe(vm._data = {}, true /* asRootData */);
  }
  if (opts.computed) { initComputed(vm, opts.computed); }
  if (opts.watch) { initWatch(vm, opts.watch); }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll mark answered when it allows me to in a few minutes.

Comment: I had to use `created()` not `mounted()` and managed to ditch the computed property `created () {this.country.label = this.countries.find(item => item.value === this.content.country).label}`

Comment: For some reason `mounted()` wasn't working. Thanks for your help though.